# how to make a show a new controller after closing another controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller, dismissviewcontroller

I am new to Swift and want to make a simple application

When the user launch the application, He sees the `FirstViewController` where there is 1 Login button, when the user tap on this button, application present a `SecondViewController` modally

On the `SecondViewController` there are text fields and an "Auth button", I want that by tapping on the "Auth Button", the `SecondViewController` dismissed and the `FirstViewController` shows the `ThirdViewController`

ok, I using self.navigationController.show() method

```
let secondVC = SecondViewController()
self.navigationController.show(secondVC, sender: self)
```

and dismiss method for dismiss VC, BUT when I try open ThirdViewController after `dismiss`, its doesn't work

```
func buttonTapped() {
    let firstVC = FirstViewController()
    let thirdVC = ThirdViewController()
    firstVC.navigationController.show(thirdVC, sender: self)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}
```

How to do it right?

I do not use storyboard, if it's important

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might want to check out [ask] to get an idea about what types of questions are successful here. In general, you'd want to show some sort of attempt that you've made and where you got stuck, rather than just laying out what you want and asking for direction.

Comment: @jnpdx Honestly, I don't have any code, of course I can write 3 swift files, but there is more unnecessary than useful information. I am using `let vc = SecondViewController()` and `self.show (vc, sender: self)` and then I don't know what to do. I need, by clicking on a button on the `SecondViewController`, close it and after that display the `thirdViewController`. i tried creating a method `func showThird() { vc = ThirdViewController(); self.show(vc, sender: self)` in the `firstViewController()`

Comment: And when the user clicks the Login button on the `secondViewController`, used the `dismiss` method, and after it, created an instance of the `FirstViewController`, and tried to call this method on him, but nothing happened

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are *"new to Swift"* ... you may want to spend more time learning the basics before trying to *"make a simple application"*.

The problem is that, at this point, you don't even know what to ask, or proper terminology.

For example, you say:

- *"gets to the FirstViewController"* ... what do you mean "gets to"?
- *"click"* instead of "tap"
- *"the `SecondViewController` closes and the `FirstViewController` opens the `ThirdViewController`"* ... "close" and "open" are ambiguous terms

I don't mean to sound harsh, but would you try to write a novel before learning the alphabet?

However, here is a quick, very simple example...

We start with `FirstViewController` as the root controller... button tap presents `SecondViewController` and sets a closure... button tap in that controller calls the closure, at which point we pass the user entered strings and replace the root controller with `ThirdViewController`:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        
        // create a "Login" button
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        btn.setTitle("Login", for: [])
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(btn)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // center the button in the view
            btn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            btn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75),
            btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
        ])
        
        // add touchUpInside action
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginBtnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func loginBtnTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        let secondVC = SecondViewController()
        
        // set the closure
        secondVC.theClosure = { [weak self] str1, str2 in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            // closure was called from SecondVC,
            //  dismiss it and then show ThirdVC
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                let thirdVC = ThirdViewController()
                
                // set the strings
                thirdVC.val1 = str1
                thirdVC.val2 = str2
                
                // replace First VC with Third VC
                UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = thirdVC
                UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            })
        }
        
        // present the second VC
        self.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var theClosure: ((String, String) -> ())?
    
    let tf1 = UITextField()
    let tf2 = UITextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGreen

        // stack view to arrange two fields and a button
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 20
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // add text fields to stack view
        [tf1, tf2].forEach { tf in
            tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect
            stack.addArrangedSubview(tf)
        }
        
        // create an "Auth" button
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        btn.setTitle("Auth", for: [])
        
        // add button to stack view
        stack.addArrangedSubview(btn)

        view.addSubview(stack)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain stack view centered horizontally, near top
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            stack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75),
            btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
        ])

        // add touchUpInside action
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(authBtnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func authBtnTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        // get the text from the two fields
        var s1 = tf1.text ?? ""
        var s2 = tf2.text ?? ""
        if s1.isEmpty { s1 = "Field 1 Empty" }
        if s2.isEmpty { s2 = "Field 2 Empty" }

        // call the closure with the two strings
        theClosure?(s1, s2)
    }

}

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var val1: String = ""
    var val2: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        // create a multi-line label
        let label = UILabel()
        label.backgroundColor = .cyan
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(label)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain the label centered in the view
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75),
        ])

        // set label text
        var s: String = "User-entered strings:"
        s += "\n\n"
        s += val1
        s += "\n\n"
        s += val2

        label.text = s
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your example works great, thanks! Misunderstanding due to incorrect terminology occurs not because I do not know the basics, but because my native language is very different from English, and I, at the moment, have to use a translator to ask a question.

The only thing I would like to do without changing the rootViewController, how can the code be improved?

Comment: @Resly34 - *"without changing the rootViewController"* ... there are ***many*** approaches, but you haven't said anything about your app structure. Are you in a NavigationController stack? Do you need `FirstViewController` to do anything else? If not, you could hide/remove the "Login" button and add/show the UI elements that would have been in `ThirdViewController`.